# Prove that spatial curves coincide

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider two regular curves parametrized by arc length $\alpha, \beta : I \to \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $k_\alpha = k_\beta$ and $\tau_\alpha = \tau_\beta$. The fundamental theorem of curves ensures there exists a unique affine orthogonal application $\sigma$ such that $\alpha = \sigma \circ \beta$. My question is: what is the minimum set of conditions we need to ensure $\sigma = id$ (this is, $\alpha= \beta$)?

My intuition is that we need to ask for $\alpha(0) = \beta(0)$, $t_\alpha(0) = t_\beta(0)$ and $n_\alpha(0) = n_\beta(0)$ (the equality can occur at any other point different from 0, of course),  but I am not sure about the necessity of that last condition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You need the point and the Frenet frames to agree at the starting point.

Comment: @TedShifrin OK. And since the binormal is completely determined by the tangent and the normal, it is sufficient to confirm equality for these two vectors, right?

Comment: Yup, right. …….